# Change a fixed nav menu to side nav bar when scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transforms

I have a fixed nav menu have a style with CSS fixed from top:

[image]

I need when I scroll down  by mouse to change this nav to be in a sidebar

like this:

[image]

any suggestion the best way to do that?

Comment: can you share your demo?

Comment: You can try to create 2 different classes in css, one for a top version and the second one for a sidebar. Then use javascript onScroll event to detect page scroll. Now get the scroll position using jquery `$(window).scrollTop()`. Then toggle css classes using jquery.

Comment: @IshimdarAhamad iam using this demo iam not sure if i can share it in site or not 

https://codyhouse.co/demo/secondary-sliding-navigation/index.html

i need to customize it

Comment: @IshimdarAhamad

Thanks iam trying it but check this demo too

Comment: this is static or dynamic site?